# How to remove the red selection marker from a winform chart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

How can I disable the red marker lines shown in the picture? They appear after clicking in a winform chart.

Thanks

[image: chart with red marker]

Comment: There must be some code behind these lines. Hunt it down and show it to us!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting CursorX and CursorY linewidth to 0 solved the problem.